# Hide filter options with 0 products in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I hide filter options when there are 0 products for it?

I'd like to show only the options with products behind.

Answer (score 1):

This one is in the Magento Admin:

1. In your admin, go to `Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes`.
2. Select the attribute that is showing on the layered navigation with 0 products.
3. Change `Use in Layered Navigation` -> `Filterable(with results)`.

That should do it. You may need to refresh/re-index and all that, not sure.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I misunderstood the system. I thought this setting means if I want to show the results or not. And I wondered that the results are shown eberytime...

Comment: No problem, don't forget to select the answers on SO, otherwise the question lingers in the "Unanswered" section (and we answer for tips ;D ).